# Take first item from Include collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code that works fine:

```
var model = db.TankCentres
            .Include(images => images.ProfileImages)
            .Where(t => t.Live == true)
            .ToList();
```

ProfileImages is a collection but I only want to take the first item, so I want to do something like:

```
var model = db.TankCentres
            .Include(images => images.ProfileImages.FirstOrDefault())
            .Where(t => t.Live == true)
            .ToList();
```

but this does not work.

How can I achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: maybe ProfileImages[0]?

Comment: I also faced same issue. I did it using model (in your example) value which is not correct. You can see this Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430419/how-to-use-firstordefault-inside-include

Comment: @StepUp, If it is LastorDefault() ?

Comment: @StepUp this does not work unfortunately

Comment: try moving the where before Include

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh that does not work either

Comment: any error(s) ? or just that evaluates to null?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path

Comment: it is really cool example, can you imitate behavior without database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this is the end:

```
var model = from t in db.TankCentres
                    where t.Live == true
                    select new ViewAllTanksViewModel
                    {
                        Id = t.Id,
                        Name = t.Name,
                        Address = t.Address,
                        Live = t.Live,
                        ExperienceId = t.ExperienceId,
                        MainImageVM = t.ProfileImages.FirstOrDefault()
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var model = db.TankCentres.Where(t => t.Live == true)
            .Select(i => new { ProfileImage = i.ProfileImages.FirstOrDefault(), TankCentre = i} )
           .ToList();
```

Comment: I get this error using that The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType8`2[TankDriving.Areas.Admin.Models.ProfileImage,TankDriving.Areas.Admin.Models.TankCentre]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TankDriving.Areas.Admin.Models.TankCentre]'.

Comment: No.above error belongs to your other code issue. Can you put debug point on 'var model' and see.

Comment: So this is working and the data is in the model, do I just have to create a viewModel to handle the data now?

Comment: I still get: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType8`2[TankDriving.Areas.Admin.Models.ProfileImage,TankDriving.Areas.Admin.Models.TankCentre]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TankDriving.ViewModels.ViewAllTanksViewModel]'.

Comment: do this., var lstTankCentres = new List<TankCentres>();
foreach(var _model in model)
{
    var tankCentre = new TankCentre();
    tankCentre = _model.TankCentre;
    tankCentre.ProfileImage = _model.ProfileImage; 
  
    lstTankCentres.Add(tankCentre );
}

Do some thing like above.

Comment: You've lost me, could you format the answer for everything that I need in my controller?